# Sum greatest values of each day from period with Django Query

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, django-orm

My proj has a model that goes like:

```
class Data(Model):
    data = FloatField(verbose_name='Data', null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = DateTimeField(verbose_name='Created at')
```

And my app creates a few hundred logs of this model per day.

I'm trying to sum only the greatest values of each day, without having to iterate over them (using only Django queries).

Is it possible without writing SQL queries?

*PS: I'm able to get the greatest 'data' of each day, so the current logic iterates over days and sums the greatest values of each day. But that solution is becoming too slow and I'd like to solve it directly into db level.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Annotations and aggregates to the rescue:

```
from django.db.models import Sum, Max
from django.db.models.functions import Trunc

report = (Data.objects
    .annotate(day=Trunc('created_at', 'day'))
    .values('day')
    .annotate(greatest=Max('data'))
    .values('greatest')
    .aggregate(total=Sum('greatest'))
)

print(report['total'])
```

The resulting SQL is almost simpler than the code:

```
SELECT SUM("greatest")
FROM
  (SELECT MAX("app_data"."data_id") AS "greatest"
   FROM "app_data"
   GROUP BY DATE_TRUNC('day', "app_data"."created_at")) subquery
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a database backed that supports `distinct` on fields (like postgres does) you can do.

```
Data.objects.order_by('created_at__date', '-data').distinct('created_at__date')
```